# How to forward all ports on a ipaddress/interface to another ipaddress on another interface

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I have tried several pages of `iptables` information on the net but they all seem to be missing a key piece of information to do what I need to do.

Background:

I work in a factory and am trying to add gateway (not entirely the right word I'm afraid) functionality to an IOT device (NanoPi R2S).
My device has 2 network interfaces:

- eth0 is connected to the plant network (10.4.42.210)
- eth0 has an alias IP address of 10.4.42.211 (on eth0:0)
- eth1 is connected to a PLC network (192.168.100.211)
- on the machine network is a PLC with an IP address of 192.168.100.42
- the PLC has a default gateway preset (not pointed at my device) and it can't be changed.

My end goal is to redirect all ports aimed at 10.4.42.211 on eth0:0 to 192.168.100.42 on eth1

I only require inbound connections to the PLC and the PLC's responses.  The PLC will not be initiating connections.

I have enabled forwarding in the kernel with `/etc/sysctl.conf` by setting `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

I've tried several examples on the internet but am struggling to understand how to diagnose or test these rules so I can figure out what needs to be done to make this work.

Update:
After scouring the man pages for `iptables` and `nat`, I have the following rules that almost work:

This forwards packets destined for the PLC to the PLC's internal address:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.4.42.211 -j DNAT --to 192.168.100.42
```

I believe this is working as my pings disappear and the counters show they are hitting this rule.

This changes the from address of anything coming from the PLC

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.100.42 -j SNAT --to 10.4.42.211
```

Unfortunately anyting coming from the PLC is sent to the gateway to resolve.  My IOT device is not the gateway set in the PLC and I can see a case where I can't change the gateway.  I tried to solve this by changing the from adress to match my IOT device but that generated an error:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.4.42.211 -j SNAT --to 192.168.100.211
Error: x_tables: ip_tables: SNAT target: used from hooks PREROUTING, but only usable from INPUT/POSTROUTING
```

Is there a way to change the from address of packets sent to the PLC so they come back to the IOT device (and when they get back, that needs to be reversed)?

Comment: You don't need to add a reverse SNAT rule for the DNAT rule. Rather, because the DNAT target does not use this host as its default gateway, you'll need to add an SNAT rule for the redirected traffics (`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.100.42 -j SNAT --to 192.168.100.211`)

Comment: @TomYan you hit the nail on the head.  Post that as an answer and I will accept it.  I was forgetting that all of these rules reverse themselves when the traffic returns.  As usual, I was overthinking it.